# wcf execute function at background

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I develop a wcf function(e.g. bulk SMS to all db users) when raised took long time.

is there any way in wcf so that respond to admin "ok we will process your request " and sms process will  execute seperatly.

Comment: Yes. Just run the actual sms-sending in a separate thread or backgroundworker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Recommendation is to separate this task on to two tasks "Prepare Messages" and "Send Messages"

1. Prepare message: prepare list of messages that will be sent to the users
2. Send Messages: loop over created messages and send them

You can use some message queuing frameworks or you can make small table to act as your queue so when the user click the button, Start background thread or task to loop over db users and insert them into the messages table, then create scheduled task to loop over the messages table and send them

This approach will give you more control as you know the messages that will be sent and the status of each message also you can add retry counts to your table